# why am I getting this error : Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process

Tags: error

I was trying out on creating a private ethereum network by following [this link](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0) .
However the first connection took too long so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it again. 
However when I try to run geth .exe I get this error message:

> WARN [01-16|09:29:36] No etherbase set and no accounts found as
>   default Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by
>   another process

Comment: now I can't type anything on geth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message

> datadir already used by another process

Usually means there's another instance of geth running. If you are on Windows use the task manager to locate the other instance of `geth` and kill it. And start again.

Comment: oh I see, I tried to attach geth but where should I attach it to?

Comment: @ethereumnoob On windows `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc` should work

Comment: I get this error: Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: Timed out waiting for pipe '\\.\pipe\geth.ipc' to come available

Comment: what is \\.\pipe\geth.ipc?

Comment: It is a windows pipe, geth uses that to communicate with the local client. The part `\\.\` refers to the local machine, `pipe\` is the type of windows object, and `geth.ipc` is the name object. Either geth is not running or it is running with different priviledges, ie Administrator vs User.

Comment: I solved it! thx