# Error when attaching geth

Tags: go-ethereum, command-line, error

cont from [first question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36428/why-am-i-getting-this-error-fatal-error-starting-protocol-stack-datadir-alre/36440?noredirect=1#comment40126_36440)

I get this error upon keying geth attach ipc:\.\pipe\geth.ipc.

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: Timed out waiting for pipe '\\.\pipe\geth.ipc' to come available
```

what exactly is this error and what should I do to attach geth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are giving the wrong ipc path, Check for this message on your log - `IPC endpoint opened:` to know the exact path at which IPC has been opened.

Comment: oh yeah I just needed another \ thx

Comment: Why I have (-1) when the answer is correct ... :D

Comment: haha who knows? here is the mark that I forgot to put

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the port of your choice by typing

```
geth attach http://localhost:8547
```

This solution worked on Win10 machine.